# MainMenu in winforms - onclick function is not being invoked

Tags: c#, winforms, events, menuitem

In my designer.cs code I have a MainMenu such as

```
this.mainMenu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MainMenu(this.components);    
this.menuItemWeigh = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();

//then
this.menuItemWeigh.Index = 0;
this.menuItemWeigh.MenuItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem[] {
this.menuItemWeighReceived,
this.menuItemWeighFWD,
this.menuItemWeighANV,
this.menuItemWeighFree,
this.menuItemWeighByAdd,
this.menuItemTM,
this.menuItemFM,
this.menuItemWeighPrepQC});
this.menuItemWeigh.OwnerDraw = true;
this.menuItemWeigh.Text = "Main Menu";
this.menuItemWeigh.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.DrawCustomMenuItem);
this.menuItemWeigh.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuItemWeigh_Click);
```

When I click on menuItemWeigh, the onclick routine does not get invoke.

What happens is that if I click on the left hand side of the menuItemWeigh, I get the submenu; clicking on any other area of menuItemWeigh results in nothing.

How can make sure that the submenu shows when the user clicks anywhere on menuItemWeigh? I was thinking to implement the onclick routine, but it doesn't get invoked at all.

Is there anything specific to this Menu control I should be aware of?

Comment: CSS? it's winforms.As in Windows application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `MainMenu` has been retired in 3.5 and `MenuStrip` is the one to be used for the menu. `MainMenu` is still somewhat compatible but with quirks.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/menustrip-in-C-Sharp/